# Quickest way to add Pods or CocoaPods in Xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, cocoapods

What is quickest way to add dependencies in Xcode project using Pods.

How to add or edit dependencies later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Terminal

```
Terminal: sudo gem install cocoapods
```

After installation done setup as

```
Terminal: pod setup --verbose
```

Once done give your project path as

```
Terminal: cd ~/Path/To/Folder Containing Project
```

Init Pod file as

```
Terminal: pod init
```

Pod file would be created in your project folder, open Pod file from project folder and add required pod like below under target, Remove these two line followed by # with required

```
"# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project"
"# platform :ios, '6.0'"
```

Final Example of POD file would be as follows:

```
platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks! 

target 'ProjectName' do

pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'

end
```

After Editing pod file save it and make sure Xcode is closed.

Run following command

```
Terminal: pod install
```

Once install done open xcworkspace instead of xcodeproj.

You are done.

0.9.0 version >=  0.9.0 but <= 0.10.0.

Comment: `use frameworks!` ...As new beta released in cocoapods,you need to use `use_frameworks!` to install...